# How to get the text of a child element of a list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I'm trying to get the text of a child element of  list. But I'm able to access only the parent element I don't know how to access the child element .

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
   <li class="active">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
      <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <i class="icon-text-width"></i>
      <span class="menu-text"> posts </span>
      <b class="arrow icon-angle-down"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="submenu">
         <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <i class="icon-text-width"></i>
            Add New Post
            </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <i class="icon-text-width"></i>
            Blog
            </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <i class="icon-desktop"></i>
            News Letter
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-list > li', function(){
    $('.nav-list > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var text=$('.active >a >span').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $('.active >a ').text(); //try it

Comment: **var text=$('.active a span').text();** would work

Comment: @Rituraj ratan, @dholakiyaankit My code returns text of span element. But what i need is I need the child list element text. That is `.subment > li >a ` text.

Comment: @ Chirag Arvadia can you tell me please, How to get the text value of `.subment > li >a `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-list a', function () {
    $('.nav-list li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text);
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qzbYR/4/)

Comment: One problem i found in your code is, it won't remove the class added to the child element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find) like,

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-list > li', function(){
    $('.nav-list > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var text=$('.active a').find('span').text();// use find()
    // or try var text=$('.active > a span').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

If you want to get the `submenu ul text` then use

```
if($(this).has('ul.submenu'))
{
    alert($.trim($(this).find('ul.submenu li').text()));
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M6NwG/)

Comment: My question is how to get the value of child list element. Means  `.subment > li >a`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav-list a').live('click', function () {
    $('.nav-list li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text);
});
```